# Anyone know a good OOP PHP MySQL class? To build queries primarily

Tags: php, mysql, oop

EDIT: Found this which works quite well for what I need: https://github.com/jstayton/QueryBuilder

I'm building a small project where I need to query a table a couple of times.

It works like this:

```
1) Multi-select box of distinct items in Column 1
2) Ajax query the db for distinct records in Column 2 where Column 1 IN (vals
   previously selected)
3) Does this 3-4 more times, gradually cutting down the available options by 
   adding IN statements to the MySQL
```

Now it's not impossible to this manually by setting up a couple pre-built queries and binding the various params to them, but I'd like to make it a bit nicer than that. Something along the lines of....

```
$qry->from("mytable");
$qry->column("col1");
$qry->column("col2");
$qry->addWhere("col1", "in", $arrayOfVals);
$qry->addWhere("col2", "in", $arrayOfVals2);
```

Or something to that effect, that will build it out in a cleaner way.

Alternatively, if someone has a suggestion on a different way to do this, I'm open to that too.

Comment: that looks great! you should totally build that query builder class d(^_^)b although, maybe the method "column" should instead be called "select", and take a possible second argument which if present will give the column an alias. and then you add a join class, which has methods 'from' and 'addOn'. and then you have a method 'join' on the query class which takes join objects. and then you have logics when putting the query together which sorts the where-clauses in the most optimal order considering the joins by looking at what tables are used in the where-clauses. awesommmme!

Comment: Why would you need a second argument for the alias though? Just add it after the column. $qry->column('column alias');

Comment: It really is easier to just learn SQL.

Comment: How about `DB::select ('col1', 'col2')->from ('mytable')->where ('col1', 'IN', $arrayOfVals)->and_where ('col2', 'IN', $arrayOfVals2)->execute ();`? Kohana's Query Builder, you could try to extract it, or just do the sensible thing and use Kohana ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number ways to do this - it all depends on your needs. You could roll your own for sure or go for something already out in the wild.

Take a look at ezSQL http://justinvincent.com/ezsql it may be right up your alley.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  ezSQL seems to be very similar to to MySQLi or PDO, but what I'm really looking for is a good query builder.

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Db_Select` has almost the exact syntax you provided. But you'd have to include quite a lot of Zend_Db_* classes for that, I don't know if it's acceptable for you.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the link you provided in your edit no longer works so for that reason, I'd recommend looking at FluentPDO aswell - http://fluentpdo.com/index.html

It has a very simple installation process and very fluid and natural query building methods which would allow for syntax similar to what you mentioned in your original question.